# OTRS install on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, otrs

I'm trying to install OTRS on ubuntu with the following shell script, but when installation finished I couldn't reach the `installer.pl` file on the webserver, and got the following error:

```
error: 403 - don't have permission.
```

The file has executable attribute, and I have root rights.

Shell script content:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2 mysql-server

cd /opt
wget http://ftp.otrs.org/pub/otrs/otrs-3.2.9.tar.gz
tar -xvzf otrs-3.2.9.tar.gz
mv otrs-3.2.9 /opt/otrs

cd /opt/otrs
bin/otrs.CheckModules.pl

apt-get install liblwp-useragent-determined-perl libapache2-mod-perl2 libnet-dns-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-smtp-tls-butmaintained-perl libyaml-perl

apt-get install libgd-text-perl libjson-xs-perl libpdf-api2-perl libtext-csv-xs-perl libxml-parser-perl

useradd -d /opt/otrs/ -c 'OTRS user' otrs
usermod -G www-data otrs

cd /opt/otrs/
cp Kernel/Config.pm.dist Kernel/Config.pm
cp Kernel/Config/GenericAgent.pm.dist Kernel/Config/GenericAgent.pm

bin/otrs.SetPermissions.pl --otrs-user=otrs --web-user=www-data --otrs-group=www-data --web-group=www-data /opt/otrs
ls -al /opt/otrs

ln -s /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-httpd.include.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/otrs.conf
a2ensite otrs
service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - don't use outdated version of OTRS. Ver.4 is available for a while now!

Secondly, please check rights on directory /opt/otrs. It seems that otrs.SetPermissions.pl scripts run unsuccessfully, therefore it haven't set required permissions to needed pl. scripts (Check if the owner of directory is OTRS not ROOT)

Please refer to this [Installation guide](http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/4.0/en/html/manual-installation-of-otrs.html)